# Dotnet Nuget/package folder very big and for each user

Tags: .net, apache, ubuntu, package, nuget

My actual setup is:

1. Ubuntu 16.04 OS
2. Apache with multi user. (each website have their user)
3. dotnet website with reverse proxy on apache

When i create a new website it generate a .nuget/package folder in user home (1gb size).

What can i do to have only 1 package folder for the entire system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create NuGet.Config files that specify the location of the global packages folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="/var/data/nuget/cache" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Projects will automatically detect a NuGet.Config file in the directory hierarchy on restore.

Not however that the NuGet cache isn't needed for production, only for development tasks. Once a website is published (`dotnet publish`) the resulting publish folder contains all assets needed to be able to run on the target machine. Even if you run locally as another user, only the user who performs the restore-build-publish steps needs a global nuget cache.

Comment: so, the 1gb .nuget package folder is not needed on the production server? I don't understand what is the correct publish strategy.

Comment: no. you only need the .netcore runtime on the server to run the output via `dotnet your.app.dll`. To generate that output on a build machine, you do call `dotnet publish -c Release` and use the output in `bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/publish`.

Comment: During publish, all assets that the project needs from the global nuget folder are copied to the publish output.

Comment: ohh now i am understanding, last question: on my server i have the dotnet 1.0.4/1.0.5 and 1.1.1/1.1.2, but don't understand what is the difference. which version of dotnet i need to have on the production server?

Comment: You should always upgrade to the latest patch releases of the minor (1.0,1.1) version you are using when they become available. When you update the CLI / SDK (dotnet-dev package), it may require the latest patch to be installed (which ppl are complaining about so it's probably going to change for 2.0 - discussion at https://github.com/dotnet/designs/issues/3)

Comment: is it possible install ONLY the runtime part, and not the sdk? and if yes..how?

Comment: yes, for ubuntu this means installing the `dotnet-sharedframework-*` packages  instead of `dotnet-dev` (e.g. `dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.2` - each version has its own package because they can be installed side-by-side) more instructions at https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu